# Proving that the set of equivalence classes of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is $[0,1)$

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we define $x \sim y$ if $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of equivalence classes, and I want to prove that the set of equivalence classes is the set $[0,1)$. Here is my attempt.

> Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define the floor of $x$, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ to be the smallest integer less than or equal to $x$. By definition, we have $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$, so $0 \leq x - \lfloor x \rfloor < 1$, so there exists $y \in [0,1)$ such that $x \sim y$. That is, every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ lives in the equivalence class of some element of $[0,1)$, where we simply write $x = s + t$ where $s = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the integer component and $t = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the fractional component, and we have $x \sim t$. Furthermore, no two elements of $[0,1)$ belong to the same equivalence class. Indeed, if $a,b$ are distinct elements of $[0,1)$, then $a-b \in (-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$, so $a-b \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $a \not \sim b$. Therefore, the set $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ of equivalence classes is exactly the interval $[0,1)$.

The thing I'm mostly unsure of the need to prove this fact in both directions. I need to show that every element of $[0,1)$ is an equivalence class, that these are all the equivalence classes, and that this description of equivalence classes doesn't include any overlap. I proved that every element belongs to some equivalence class $[0,1)$ and that there isn't any overlap,  but I don't think I proved that each element of $[0,1)$ is an equivalence class. I don't know exactly how to prove that, other than to say that if I fix $r \in [0,1)$ and find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x - \lfloor x \rfloor = r$.

I'd be very interested on some feedback on the proof and on the appropriate sequencing of steps.

Comment: every element belongs to an equivalence class, by definition. The question is whether distinct elements $x,y\in[0,1)$ have distinct equivalence classes, and you have proven that yes they have distinct equivalence classes

Comment: Some potential confusion might be reduced by saying "show that $[0,1)$ is a collection of _representatives_for_ the equivalence classes". Perhaps even more carefully "irredundant representatives". E.g., as @ChrisSanders comments, every element of the set is in _some_ equivalence class, so that's not a question... but is perhaps obscured by a somewhat glib terminology. :)

Comment: I think I understand now. Every element is already an equivalence class. The problem boils down to showing that the elements of $[0,1)$, as equivalence classes, are mutually exclusive and exhaustive. Is that right?

Comment: yes you can put it that way

Comment: sorry, I should have said: formally the problem should be to prove that the function $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $x\mapsto \overline{x}$ is a bijection, where $\overline{x}$ denotes the equivalence class to which $x$ belongs

Comment: @ChrisSanders That explanation makes a lot of sense to me. Just to be sure I fully understand, is that a formalization of what I wrote above? The one difference I see is that I'm calling $[0,1)$ the "set of equivalence classes" but it's really $[x]$ for some $x \in [0,1)$.

Comment: yes, the proof you lay out is more or less correct. But expressing your goal in terms of a formal statement would ideally resolve doubts as to whether this or that has really been proven. So $f$ is surjective because $y\sim y-\lfloor y\rfloor\in[0,1)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, as you have shown. And $f$ is injective because as you have already stated, for distinct $a,b\in[0,1)$, we have $a-b\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$, so $a-b$ is not an integer, so $a \not \sim b$